# is there a way to solve IE10&9 wider font rendering difference?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, fonts, rendering

I'm having a problem with the rendering of arial in font IE10 & 9;
on IE7,8,Chrome,FF, it works just like I see it on dreamweaver,
But IE10 & 9 the font gets much wider, making my text jumps into an extra row.

Neither Reset.css or normalize.css have helped.

Screenshot:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    background-color: gray;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
} 

#container {
    border: 1px solid #DCD7D4;
    width: 768px;
    min-height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 8px;
}
#left {
    float: left;
    width: 580px;
    min-height: 400px;
    background-color: #FBFBFB;
    color: #565656;
}

#margin {
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    margin-left: 18px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    margin-top: 11px;
}

.text {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #565656;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 21px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}

-->
</style>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
    <div id="margin">
      <p class="text">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA<br>
        AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA<br>
AAAA AAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA aaa aaaaaaaa</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br style="clear: left;" />
</div>


</body>
```

[Here's the jsfiidle](http://jsfiddle.net/cQnG5/)

Thanks

Comment: Use a reset.css stylesheet or a normalize.css stylesheet.

Comment: Good question. If I take the width out of the div id=left, then it all fits.
From what I can see, it seems that IE10 renders the font differently. Arial looks wider.

Comment: I don't think you can correctly use width with floats in new IEs can you? If you specify width it is gonna try to fit into this width n matter what.

Comment: @AgnosticDev neither of these resets have helped...

Comment: I'm probably missing something here, but your fiddle looks the same on IE9,10 as it does on latest Chrome and Firefox. Would be nice if you posted a screenshot of the problem and the expected result.

Comment: I'm using WIN 8, maybe IE renders it different? I'll post one soon

Comment: When I open the fiddle in your question in Chrome or Firefox (on Mac), the result looks like your second screenshot labeled "IE9/10 on WIN8".

Comment: are you sure? how can that be explained?

Comment: See my explanation below. Hope it's helpful. I suggest changing the question title and adding tags so people could find this question and contribute to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between your screenshots actually comes from the differences in font rendering between the browsers in question. Below is a scaled up screenshot of the A letters in your fiddle (after adding `letter-spacing: 0;`) in Chrome and IE9 on Win7.

[image]

As you can see, even though it's the same font (Arial), `font-size`, `font-weight` and `letter-spacing` in both cases, IE9 renders letters a bit wider, which makes the lines/words longer.

IE9 uses DirectWrite mode/technology to render fonts as opposed to the GDI mode used by IE6-8, as well as Chrome, Opera (and sometimes Firefox) on Windows machines ([source](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/24/a-closer-look-at-font-rendering/)). Which explains why IE9 (and above) render fonts different than other browsers on Windows.

According to the same article above:

> DirectWrite not only gives smoother outlines, it also applies subpixel rendering to PostScript fonts. Unlike TrueType rendering, however, it allows for more gray pixels in order to reflect stroke weights more realistically. That makes it well-balanced, and similar to Mac OS rendering.

DirectWrite font rendering being similar (but not the same as) Mac OS font rendering, probably explains why the result I was getting in Chrome and Firefox on OSX was similar to what you're getting in IE9.

**Update:** One thing you could try is experimenting with different web fonts. [In this example](http://jsbin.com/uxETiKuk/5), I have used Source Sans Pro (Google font) and you can see that the difference in rendering between IE9 and Chrome is less noticeable.

Comment: thanks, you are right. I wonder what's the best way to deal with this? simply add more width to the DIV, even though in that case it would create too much extra space in all other browsers.. or is there a better solution?

Comment: Why not just let the text flow normally? Is it important that it takes up exactly the same space in all browsers? If you tell me more about the actual end result you're after I might be able to help with a workaround.

Comment: [Here's a fiddle illustrating the problem](http://fiddle.jshell.net/tzQ7a/), as you can see, I have a button close to the bottom, and whenever the text slides, it causes the last row to be covered by that button. maybe there's a better way to position all these elements so they would adapt?

Comment: One way to solve this is to add bottom margin to `#area` so that it never overlaps the button. I've added new CSS at the very bottom of this [updated fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/tzQ7a/2/)

Comment: Thanks! this seems like a good solution, but I've noticed that it's enough to add the bottom margin only, can you explain the additional changes - the `padding/margin` of 99999px and the `overflow:hidden` (as it works without them as well)?

Comment: These are to make all 3 columns appear to have equal heights. If you remove those styles, there will be a gap at the bottom of the right/middle columns if the left column had more content.

Comment: oh yes now I notice it, what about the overflow? what does it do?

Comment: It's also part of a trick called 'one true layout' used to give columns equal heights. `overflow: hidden;` on the container hides the extra column heights created by the large padding/margins.You can read more about it [here](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/).